# Power Bi DAX Statement

Tags: powerbi, tableau-api

Need help rewriting a Tableau equation to DAX. Any help yall can provide would help very much. Thanks again

```
IFNULL(IF ([Column1] = 1
            OR [Column2] = 1)
        AND([Column3] = 1
            OR [Column4] = 1
            OR [Column5] = 1
            OR [Column6] = 1
            OR [Column7] = 1)
        AND [Column8] = 0
    THEN 'A&C'
ELSEIF ([Column1] = 1
            OR [Column2] = 1)
        AND([Column3] = 0
            AND [Column4] = 0
            AND [Column5] = 0
            AND [Column6] = 0
            AND [Column7] = 0)
        AND [Column8] = 0
    THEN 'A Only'
ELSEIF ([Column1] = 0
            OR [Column2] = 0)
        AND([Column3] = 1
            OR [Column4] = 1
            OR [Column5] = 1
            OR [Column6] = 1
            OR [Column7] = 1)
        AND [Column8] = 0
    THEN 'C Only'
ELSEIF [Column8] = 1
    THEN 'NIAN'
END, 'NIAN')
```

I have been trying to utilize Switch and True and a mixture of && ||